# Como invocar e usar corretamente a função js-hs1?

Tags: javascript, criptografia, sha1

Necessito criptografar uma frase com SHA1, mas como eu não obtenho nada de retorno acredito que não estou fazendo certo! Alguém sabe como fazer corretamente?

Tenho o seguinte trecho de um script, onde tenho uma variável que armazena a frase e a a seguir a função que supostamente me devolveria um hash SHA1:

```
const sha1 = require ('js-sha1')

var frase = "when in doubt, leave it out. joshua bloch"
var cryptoFrase = crypto(frase)
alert(cryptoFrase)

function crypto(txt){
    sha1 (resp)
    var hash = sha1.create ()
    hash.update (resp)
    hash.hex ()

    return hash
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amigo, pela sua pergunta não da pra ter certeza se você quer calcular o hash no front (navegador) ou no back (nodejs), mas segue abaixo as duas maneiras:

> **Pelo Navegador**

Você pode utilizar o [SubtleCrypto.digest()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/digest) que já vem embutido nos navegadores.
Segue abaixo um exemplo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    <input type="text" name="texto1" id="texto1">
    <br>
    <input type="button" value="Calcular Hash" onclick="criarHash()">
    <br>
    <textarea name="hashtexto" id="hash" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
    
    
    <script>
        async function criarHash() {
            const texto = document.getElementById('texto1').value;
            const buffer = new TextEncoder( 'utf-8' ).encode( texto );
            const digest = await crypto.subtle.digest('SHA-1', buffer);
            const hash = Array.from(new Uint8Array(digest)).map( x => x.toString(16).padStart(2,'0') ).join('');
            document.getElementById('hash').value = hash;    
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

> **Pelo NodeJs**

Se estiver tentando calcular o hash pelo back-end primeiro será necessário instalar a biblioteca [js-sha1](https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-sha1):

```
npm i js-sha1
```

Depois em seu código pode ser feito desta maneira (conforme indicado na página da própria biblioteca):

```
const sha1 = require ('js-sha1');

sha1('teste');
var hash = sha1.create();
hash.update('teste');
hash.hex();
```

Comment: @TadeuAgostini como assim?

Comment: Vlw Murililo, acho que estou chegando la.
Só que o impase agora é o retorno que obtenho da sua primeira sujestão:`obj.resumo_criptografico = criarHash(txt)
  async function criarHash(txt) {
    const buffer = new TextEncoder( 'utf-8' ).encode( txt )
    const digest = await crypto.subtle.digest('SHA-1', buffer)
    const hash = Array.from(new Uint8Array(digest)).map( x => x.toString(16).padStart(2,'0') ).join('')
    alert(hash)
    return hash
}
alert(obj.resumo_criptografico)` Pois meu objetivo é add o hash a meu objeto so que quando eu o printo mostra  [object Promise]

Comment: @TadeuAgostini para fazer o que você esta querendo tem que tratar a resposta como uma Promise, para isso remova o seu código `obj.resumo_criptografico = criarHash(txt)` e adicione o seguinte no lugar `criarHash("teste").then((result)=>{
            obj.resumo_criptografico = result;
            alert(obj.resumo_criptografico);
            
        });`

Comment: @TadeuAgostini só mais uma coisa, se a reposta lhe ajudou com sua dúvida de como calcular o hash por favor considera marca-la como correta para ajudar outras pessoas com a mesma dúvida que você

Comment: Murilo esse ultimo trecho de code que vc sugeriu, ele printa correto apenas no momento que esta sendo executado mas quando vou usar obj.resumo_criptografico mais tarde ele me retorna vazio, como isso?

Comment: @TadeuAgostini acho que você não esta entendendo o conceito de Promise, a execução dela é assíncrona, ou seja, se vc esta em um método que é sincrono ele não vai esperar pelo retorno da promise, ele vai chamar a promise (que vai rodar 'paralelamente') e vai continuar a execução do restante do código mesmo que a promise não tenha retornado ainda. Por isso que quando vc tenta fazer alguma coisa com o `obj.resumo_criptografico` logo depois de chamar a `criarHash` ele esta vazio, você deve trabalhar com ele dentro do `then`.

Comment: Murilo realmente não estava entendendo, mas esse seu ultimo comentário foi muito esclarecedor! Obrigado mais uma vez, beijos. =*

Comment: Mas mais uma coisa Murilo esse calculo de hash me retorna um valor diferente do que é esperado do retorno de um SHA1 exemplo: esperado = cf726026091c2eebfbedff1c4cc0b98afee6219e    retorno= 3217accf836703467f2af0f195edc3d0fcb5a9dd   pro que isso?

Comment: @TadeuAgostini, tem certeza que esse Hash que você esta esperando é SHA1? Qual o texto que esta gerando esse hash? Testei nestes sites o texto "teste" e esta dando o mesmo hash que no meu exemplo [aqui](http://www.sha1-online.com/) e [aqui](http://emn178.github.io/online-tools/sha1.html), este segundo inclusive é da própria biblioteca js-sha1 que você queria utilizar.

Comment: é verdade tinha uma divergência que não percebi